# Is it good practice to use form-group class without form tag in bootstrap 4?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Can we use form-group class without adding form tag, I mean is it a good practice to do so?

Dhiraj Dhakal

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes We can do it . But it is recommended to do so.